# Oracle DB: Convert timestamp (CET/CEST) columns to UTC while doing Oracle export/import

Tags: oracle, timestamp, utc, impdp, expdp

My issue is that my oracle db has timestamp(6) column (without any timestamp information) but the timestamps are stored in CET/CEST (Europe/Berlin).

We need to correct the timestamps to UTC (because we already have issues when time  switches from CEST to CET - e.g 28.10.2018)

I already found the following how it could be done via update script:
[How to update a TIMESTAMP column to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090932/how-to-update-a-timestamp-column-to-timestamp-with-time-zone-in-oracle)

As we are also planning to migrate from 11 to 12 - my question is if it could also be done during the dump exp / imp (expdp / impdp)?

Answer (score 2):

The correct conversion would be this one:

```
 FROM_TZ(YOUR_COLUMN, 'Europe/Berlin')  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

this returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value. If you prefer to get a `TIMESTAMP` then you can use

```
 SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(YOUR_COLUMN, 'Europe/Berlin')
```

However, I don't know how to include this in import/export. I assume you have to use [REMAP_DATA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-B1D13216-93D3-4FFC-A0BB-082E133FD2B9.htm#SUTIL861):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Convert_Date AS       
    FUNCTION TO_UTC(ts IN TIMESTAMP) RETURN TIMESTAMP;
END Convert_Date;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Convert_Date AS

FUNCTION TO_UTC(ts IN TIMESTAMP) RETURN TIMESTAMP
BEGIN
    RETURN SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(ts, 'Europe/Berlin');    
END;

END Convert_Date;
/
```

And then use this import parameter:

```
REMAP_DATA=[schema.]tablename.column_name:Convert_Date.TO_UTC
```